# How to use a complicated For...Each... loop (or a better method)?

Tags: vba, loops, file-io, foreach

I found an idea that might be able to solve my problem, the For...Each... loop. However, it's a little more complicated than a typical loop.

I have three modules.

1. Concatenates an original file name, using a suffix, i, starting at "-001" and increasing by one each cycle.
2. Concatenates a new file path that has just been created, adding a suffix, i, starting at "-001" and increasing by one each cycle.
3. Uses the program to replace the old file with the new file within a program called Autodesk Inventor.

The problem is that I need the third module to replace the components and then tell both module one and module two to move to the next i. I think a for....each... loop may be able to do this but I'm not sure how to make that work since it would be referencing i from two other modules rather than its own. Anyone have any ideas?

I can try to post my codes from my three modules, but for some reason the formatting isn't listening to me right now.

Someone requested I post it anyways. Hopefully it will reformat itself.

Module 1:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub OldNameiLoop()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim NameStr2 As String
    Dim OldNamePath As String

    NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text
    OldNamePath = NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

    Do While i < 99
    i = i + 1
    If 'Something Happens Here' Then
    '3-character string created by using the Right() function
    Next i
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If

    Loop
    End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function NewNameiLoop()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim NewNamePath As String


    NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
    NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

    Do While i < 99                               'Counts with the file name up to -099
    i = i + 1
        If 'Something happens here' Then
    Loop

        Else: Exit Function

        End If

    End Function
```

Module 3:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function ReplaceComponent()

    Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence
    Set oOccurrence = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences.OldNamePath
    oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True

    End Function
```

There is more information here:
[Inventor Forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Inventor-Customization/Talking-to-Inventor-Wait/td-p/4890596)

I've combined them all in to this:

```
Option Explicit
Public i As Integer


Public Function ReplaceComponent()


Dim NameStr As String
Dim NewNamePath As String

Dim NameStr2 As String
Dim OldNamePath As String


NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"


NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text
OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"



Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence
Set oOccurrence = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences.OldNamePath
oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True

Do While i < 99
i = i + 1

Loop

End Function
```

But it's now getting stuck with an error 91. Did I make your changes incorrectly or is this a whole new problem? This is the error line..

```
Set oOccurrence = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences.OldNamePath
```

Edit 2 (from Inventor Customization Forum):

```
Sub ReplaceComponent()
   Dim NameStr As String
   Dim NewNamePath As String

   Dim NameStr2 As String
   Dim OldNamePath As String

   For i = 0 To 99 Step 1
      NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
      NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

  NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text
  OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

  Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence 
  For Each oOcc As ComponentOccurrence in ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences 
     If oOcc.ReferencedDocumentDescriptor.FullDocumentName = OldNamePath Then 
        Set oOccurrence = oOcc 
        Exit For
     End If 
  Next oOcc

  'Then you can replace
  oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True
   Next i
End Sub
```

This still doesn't quite work. I'm getting an "Expected : In" Error, but it's getting closer and closer!

[Link to Forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Inventor-Customization/Run-Time-Error-91/m-p/4896712/highlight/false)

Comment: Turns out it was my screen contrast. I changed it this morning. Here it is! :)

Comment: I've been experimenting, so it will look a little silly. But basically, this used to display a MsgBox of the file paths so I could make sure it was concatenating the name correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the simple answer would be to declare a **public variable i.**

```
Public i As Integer
```

In your module 3, Function ReplaceComponent, you can then set `i=i+1` at the end of the function and use this variable further in both Sub OldNameiLoop and Function NewNameiLoop.

Make sure to delete `Dim i As Double` from both Sub OldNameiLoop and Function NewNameiLoop.

No need to use a for-each loop I believe.

---

EDIT: more detailed I would suggest something like this to improve your latest version:

```
Option Explicit



Public Function ReplaceComponent()

Dim i as integer 'no need to declare public if you put everything in one function
Dim NameStr As String
Dim NewNamePath As String

Dim NameStr2 As String
Dim OldNamePath As String


NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"


NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text
OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt" 'not sure if correct, I think you need to add Renamer.Path_Text.text here just like for your NewNamePath above.



Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence
Set oOccurrence = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences.OldNamePath 
'Not sure why you get the error, but maybe because of what you I commented above for   
'OldNamePath. Otherwise post the error here as well, including the contents of OldNamePath 
'at the moment of the error.
oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True

Do While i < 99 'This entire do while loop does nothing in your function except for adding
i = i + 1       'up i untill it is 99. Then it just exits your function. If you want to
                'repeat the entire process 99 times, you want to put this first line right below
Loop            'the last Dim-line

End Function
```

Comment: That solves the issue of using the i's in multiple modules, so that's great!!! I still have to get my newnameiloop and oldnameiloop to listen to that i + 1 though...any ideas of how to do that? I've only been working with VBA for a few weeks. Sorry for the newbie questions!

Comment: You don't need to make your newnameiloop and oldnameiloop listen to anything. The i=i+1 increases your public variable with 1 at the end of your ReplaceComponent function. That public variable is then used in your newnameiloop and oldnameiloop and thus already using the increased i (i+1). Try it out and let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried combining them all in to one module since it kept losing "NewNamePath". I wrote my changes above as well as the issue it caused. :/

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your new code. Read my comments and try to improve your code as proposed.